# Как по сессии идентифицировать данные пользователя в Django

Tags: python, django

Авторизованный пользователь оставляет комментарий на странице. Как мне реализовать представление `got_comment(request)`. Есть модель:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    comment_nickname = models.ForeignKey(Stranger,
           on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
    comment_text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

Ключ сессии идентификации пользователей - request.session['stranger_id'].
Думал реализовать как-то так:

```
def got_comment(request):
    c = Comment(comment_text=request.POST['comment_text'],
             comment_nickname="""""")
```

Но не знаю что писать в конце строчки.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь сохранить комментарий в базу?

Comment: Да, пытаюсь сохранить в базу. Там же в представлении создаётся экземпляр модели.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def got_comment(request):
c = Comment(comment_text=request.POST['comment_text'],
            comment_nickname=Stranger.objects.get(id = request.session['stranger_id']))
c.save()
```

Comment: id является встроенной функцией Python